# Dynamically added style doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css

I've got an element class with the following CSS:

```css
#item-group-navigation li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: MyriadProReg;
    vertical-align: -1px;
}
```

And I add the following class using jQuery after a certain event:

```css
.item-group-selected{
    color:rgb(245, 255, 0);!important
}
```

But the problem is that the dynamically added style doesn't work. The default style is applied instead. I tried to use the `!important` keyword but it doesn't work. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: !important should go before the semi-colon

Comment: Did you mean to withdraw the accepted answer? If so, is there more you need help with on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `!important` it needs to be placed before the semicolon.

```css
color:rgb(245, 255, 0) !important;
```

You shouldn't need to use that though. Ensure that your class is added after any other styles which may override that color and inspect your page to see where the current color is being computed from.

For instance, if your CSS looks like this:

```css
.item-group-selected{
    color:rgb(245, 255, 0);
}

#item-group-navigation li a {
    color: white;
}
```

You should move the `.item-group-selected` option *below* the `#item-group-navigation` and/or give it higher [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/):

```css
#item-group-navigation li a {
    color: white;
}

#item-group-navigation li.item-group-selected a {
    color:rgb(245, 255, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't supposed to be:

```
.item-group-selected{
    color:rgb(245, 255, 0) !important;
}
```

Take note of the location of the semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
.item-group-selected{
    color:rgb(245, 255, 0) !important;
}
```

The `;` should be after `!important`